# This site use which of the technology for render photo?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, image-manipulation

This [**site**](https://www.theshadestore.com/window-treatments/product/pinch-pleat-drapery) use which of the technology for the preview curtain and photo rendering?

How to apply **curtain wrinkle to pattern fabric**?

I can apply pattern to curtain but can't apply wrinkle!

Sample code appreciated.